# How do Catholic apologists explain the cross to a Muslim?

Tags: catholicism, apologetics, islam, cross, christianity-in-india

I'm an American Catholic currently living in India and teaching Communicative English to students of an Islamic school (ages 5 - 14). I am trying to live on the fence and keeping my faith promoted and subdued as necessary for my profession. I am already "leading by example" of a righteous, caring, loving Christian, but now some students are starting to ask me questions about Christianity. I'm thrilled and nervous at the same time.

When a seventh grade student asks me "What does the symbol of a cross mean?", I want to present it in a way that answers the question correctly, but also is stated in a way that bridges the two religions and doesn't cause a rift in administration.

What is an overview of methods recommended by published Roman Catholic missionaries and missiologists for explaining the cross to curious Muslims?

Comment: Welcome! This is a good question, but to make it more answerable here (less "opinion-based"), I've modified it to specifically ask for the practice of Christian missionaries: hopefully you still find that helpful. If you haven't already done so, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: There are as many approaches to this as there are missionaries. And we aren't in a position to tell you which is best. Although I think it's a good question, I don't think it's a good fit for our site.

Comment: "I want to present it in a way that answers the question correctly, but also is stated in a way that bridges the two religions and doesn't cause a rift in administration." Unfortunately there is a huge rift that can't easily be bridged: Islam vehemently denies that Jesus died.

Comment: @Nathaniel: It's a question, in part, of teaching style. I doubt there's anything within Catholic doctrine which demands which teaching style is used by missionaries. There is doctrine about the cross, but that's not specific to missionaries. I suspect the closest you'll get to an official Catholic "rule" about how to teach the cross to Muslims is "teach the Catholic doctrine." But that's not what the OP wants to know... they want to know *how* to present this doctrine.

Comment: @Flimzy Right: I know this won't be in the Catechism or other sources of doctrine, but I know there are missiological books and manuals that would at least touch on the *how* that are written by Protestants, and I'm sure there are some by Roman Catholics as well.

Comment: I realize now that this at least needs to be narrowed to Nicene Christianity, since JW missionaries are going to treat the cross very differently, but personally I don't think it needs to be narrowed further than that.

Comment: @Nathaniel Mission to muslims is a huge broad topic, and there's no consensus for how it is best accomplished. I don't think this can successfully be focused except by scoping it to a single individual or mission agency, which does not seem like what the OP wants.

Comment: The edit to scope this to Catholic missals should be sufficient to make it on-topic and not too broad.

Comment: @Nathaniel: Some Nicene Christians advocate a "cram it down their throat, threaten brimstone and hellfire" methods of mission work. Others advocate a "service" model.  And there are countless others. Clearly "Nicene Christianity" is nowhere near narrow enough. I doubt even any single denomination is specific enough _for this question_, since it's really a matter of personal technique.

Comment: `What methods do published Roman Catholic missionaries...` now it's a list question. The scope change hasn't really fixed the underlying problem.

Comment: @Flimzy I realized that and switched it to an overview.  I think the context makes it clear that a "cram it down their throat" approach isn't what the OP is looking for, but would  editing to "sensitively explaining" in the final line help clarify?

Comment: @Nathaniel: I don't think it would. "sensitivity" is pretty subjective... and sounds like a "pastoral advice" question. Also, many Christians (likely including some Catholics) believe that trying to make the gospel "sensitive" is "watering it down" and that only a "tough love" approach is appropriate.

Comment: I'm realizing we need to hash this sort of thing out in meta posts like [this one](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/5720/21576) rather than in question comments...

Comment: The only way I can see to make a question about mission approaches on-topic is to ask how a *specific missionary* does/did something.

Comment: A search of "ministry to muslims" turns up many results. Check out this one: http://www.answering-islam.org/Shamoun/defense.htm

Comment: A place to start: [Islam and the Crucifixion](http://www.catholic.com/blog/jon-sorensen/islam-and-the-crucifixion).

Answer (score 1):

What the saints have said about Islam [cf. [What Did the Saints Say about Islam? | 1P5](http://www.onepeterfive.com/what-did-the-saints-say-about-islam/)] may assist you in this regard. For example [St. John of Damascus’s Critique of Islam](http://orthodoxinfo.com/general/stjohn_islam.aspx) *(sans references)* has a paragraph on how to answer the accusation of idolatry when Christians venerate the cross:

> They furthermore accuse us of being idolaters, because we venerate the
>   cross, which they abominate. And we answer them: ‘How is it, then,
>   that you rub yourselves against a stone in your Ka’ba and kiss
>   and embrace it?’ Then some of them say that Abraham had relations with
>   Agar upon it, but others say that he tied the camel to it, when he was
>   going to sacrifice Isaac. And we answer them: ‘Since Scripture says
>   that the mountain was wooded and had trees from which Abraham cut wood
>   for the holocaust and laid it upon Isaac, and then he left the
>   asses behind with the two young men, why talk nonsense? For in that
>   place neither is it thick with trees nor is there passage for asses.’
>   And they are embarrassed, but they still assert that the stone is
>   Abraham’s. Then we say: ‘Let it be Abraham’s, as you so foolishly say.
>   Then, just because Abraham had relations with a woman on it or tied a
>   camel to it, you are not ashamed to kiss it, yet you blame us for
>   venerating the cross of Christ by which the power of the demons and
>   the deceit of the Devil was destroyed.’ This stone that they talk
>   about is a head of that Aphrodite whom they used to worship and whom
>   they called Khabár. Even to the present day, traces of the carving are
>   visible on it to careful observers.

---

As regards *'I want to present it in a way that answers the question correctly, but also is stated in a way that bridges the two religions and doesn't cause a rift in administration'* the Church and Scipture teaches that we have to speak the truth, but with Charity. With the help of God and knowing your audience, you have to figure the how.

- Cf. [Encyclical: Caritas in veritate (June 29, 2009) | BENEDICT XVI](http://w2.vatican.va/content/benedict-xvi/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_ben-xvi_enc_20090629_caritas-in-veritate.html).
- Cf. [1 Pt 3:14-16 (RSVCE)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Peter%203:14-16&version=RSVCE) & [Eph 4:15 (RSVCE)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ephesians%204%3A15&version=RSVCE).

---

Perhaps a modern resource: [Franciscan University Presents: Catholics and Islam | Franciscan University of Steubenville](https://youtu.be/UZBXHxHbZZE).